# Running multiple thread for implementing array

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

```
#include <time.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t pthread; sem_t th;

void *countOccurences(void* args){
    sem_wait(&th);
    sleep(2);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pthread);
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    int num[200000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++){
            num[i] = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 200000; j++){
                    if (i == num[j]){
                    count++;
            }
    }
    printf("%d occurs %d times \n", i, count);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pthread);
    sem_post(&th); }

int main(){
    pthread_t thID[1];
    sem_init (&th, 0, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
            pthread_create(&thID[i], NULL, countOccurences, NULL);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
            pthread_join(thID[i],NULL);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy (&pthread);
    sem_destroy(&th);
    return 0; } ~
```

As I want to optimize the time execution of the code so I have been requested for doing multiple threads creating 200000 array with random numbers from 1 to 1000. However, when I did like this, the output is 3 times array. But I expect to have 1 array run only. How can I fix this?

Output:
...

```
986 occurs 208 times
987 occurs 229 times
988 occurs 207 times
989 occurs 203 times
990 occurs 217 times
991 occurs 178 times
992 occurs 178 times
993 occurs 177 times
994 occurs 170 times
995 occurs 196 times
996 occurs 212 times
997 occurs 178 times
998 occurs 219 times
999 occurs 228 times
1000 occurs 196 times
1 occurs 196 times
2 occurs 211 times
3 occurs 203 times
4 occurs 213 times
5 occurs 193 times
6 occurs 213 times
7 occurs 195 times
8 occurs 188 times
9 occurs 203 times
10 occurs 196 times
11 occurs 198 times
12 occurs 196 times
13 occurs 209 times
```

...

Output expect:

```
1 occurs 190 times
2 occurs 211 times
3 occurs 223 times
4 occurs 204 times
5 occurs 208 times
6 occurs 191 times
7 occurs 216 times
8 occurs 181 times
9 occurs 209 times
10 occurs 228 times
11 occurs 186 times
12 occurs 196 times
13 occurs 212 times
14 occurs 207 times
15 occurs 198 times
16 occurs 181 times
17 occurs 207 times
18 occurs 175 times
19 occurs 183 times
20 occurs 213 times
21 occurs 195 times
22 occurs 226 times
```

until 1000:

```
989 occurs 200 times
990 occurs 185 times
991 occurs 206 times
992 occurs 188 times
993 occurs 215 times
994 occurs 213 times
995 occurs 210 times
996 occurs 207 times
997 occurs 211 times
998 occurs 187 times
999 occurs 191 times
1000 occurs 195 times
```

Comment: Do you want to create an array of random numbers of length 200000 using 4 threads? I don't understand why do you need multi threading at all, can't you simply use a for loop for creating such an array? What is the exact requirement?

Comment: I use multithread for making the execution being faster because I was asked to compare the original method with thread method to see why thread can help faster

Comment: How do you expect, the 3 threads synchronize the access to one single array? Why would they? You call the same function for 3 threads. This function has 1 array (in each thread) and creates all the 200000 numbers (also in each thread) and finally prints the count (again in each thread). If you want 1 array, provide one single array to all the threads. Think about which thread should do which part of the array and what should happen afterwards.

Comment: This is also causing undefined behaviour: `&thID[i]` This array can only hold 1 value but `i` can go up to `4`. BTW: Are you sure you get the output 3 times? With 5 threads you should get 5 times the same output. (In command above I erronously mentioned 3 threads but they are 5)

Comment: @Gerhardh can you please show me the code because this is what I want but I don't know how to do it (5 times are exact when my command line only show 3 so that's my mistake). Thanks

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem and do you understand the code?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes I'm trying to implement and test it. But thanks for your code, it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign different tasks to your thread. In your version each thread does the complete task and each thread does the same thing. That will never speed up your program.

You need to make one array accessible to each of the thread.
And you need to tell each thread what part of it shall be handled.
Also you deactivate any multithreading by locking the semaphore (and the mutex) during the whole time your thread function is running. That is essentially the same as calling the function 5 times in a row. There is nothing going on in parallel.

A fixed (but untested) version could look like this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

typedef struct {
  int             *data;
  size_t           num;
  volatile int   (*count)[1001];
} thread_data_t;

void *countOccurences(void* args) {
  thread_data_t *thread_data = (thread_data_t*)args;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < thread_data->num; i++) {
    thread_data->data[i] = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < thread_data->num; j++) {
      if (i == thread_data->data[j]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    thread_data->count[i] += count;   
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  int num[200000];
  volatile int count[1001] = {0};
  pthread_t thID[5];
  thread_data data[5] = {
    [0] = { &num[0],      40000, count},
    [1] = { &num[40000],  40000, count},
    [2] = { &num[80000],  40000, count},
    [3] = { &num[120000], 40000, count},
    [4] = { &num[160000], 40000, count},
  };

  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pthread_create(&thID[i], &data[i], countOccurences, NULL);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pthread_join(thID[i],NULL);
  }
  pthread_mutex_destroy (&mutex);

  for (size_t i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    printf("%d occurs %d times\n", i, count[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```